# Thin the stroke of PNG in JS

Tags: javascript, image, svg, png, stroke

Is there a way to take a black png image with a transparent background and shrink down the stroke of the line by a few pixels while maintains image size?

I would need to to be able to overlay on top of the original without covering the whole thing

I have tried converting to SVG so I can adjust the stroke but when converting to SVG stroke is set to none and it’s just the path data

I have tried thinning algorithms with bitmap but they seem to do nothing.

What I am trying to do is exactly what photoshops contract method does but I cannot find any way to automate this in JS

Comment: Why not just do it in Photoshop?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.